# Call to a member function query() on a non-object in PHP when trying to access parent constructor in php

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I don't seem to be able to access the parent class constructor In PHP.

Here is the code

```
class Mysql
{
  const SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB;

  function Mysql()
  {
    return mysqli_connect(self::SERVER, ETC);
  }
}

class Mysql_Select extends Mysql
{
  function Mysql_Select()
  {
    $conn = new Mysql();
    etc
  } 
}
```

I'm trying to keep the actual connection in the parent class, but I get the non-object error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong

First thing is that PHP4-style constructors are deprecated, use `__construct` method to define a costructor.

Second is that you must not return from constructor but rather keep the connection object inside class as instance property.

Third is that you must call parent methods using `parent` keyword.

```
class Mysql
{
    const SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB;

    protected $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect(self::SERVER, ETC);
    }
}

class Mysql_Select extends Mysql
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // use $this->conn here from the parent class.
    } 
}
```

Comment: I get the same error with your code. It works if I break down the code like so:  $conn = mysqli_connect and then return $conn in the same function kind of like parent::getConn() <- this function is in the parent class

Comment: That's because you're confusing procedural `mysqli` with objective one. To have `$this->conn->query` you need `new Mysqli(params)`